# Is it allowed to work for two government agencies in Canada?

Tags: canada, labor-law

this is very unusual but I am asking anyway,

I know it is not illegal to have two employers (or more) in Canada, the question is about the two employers both being part of the federal government.
A related question can also be if one is from the federal government and the other is a provincial government.

Thank you

Comment: In what capacity? Salaried? Self-employed?